# How would I write a variable to call all margins on all elements on the page with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Title pretty much says it all, I duno if this is basic or advanced but I need a variable that will be the sum of all top and bottom margins of every element on the page that has margins. I don't need the left or right ones. Can this be done easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sumMargins() {
    var total = 0;
    $("*").each(function() {
        var top = parseInt($(this).css("marginTop"));
        var bottom = parseInt($(this).css("marginBottom"));
        total += (top + bottom);
    });
    return total;
}
```

See [**this fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/XGzTD/)

Comment: When using this, take note that this sums **all margins in the DOM**, including that of the `body` element, etc. You can change the `$("*")` selector to `$("body").children()` or something else if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 0;

$('*').each(function() {
    x += parseInt($(this).css('margin-top'));
    x += parseInt($(this).css('margin-bottom'));
});

alert(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/qQ6sB/

```
function allMargins() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.container *').each(function(i) {
        var currentTop = parseInt($(this).css('margin-top'));
        var currentBottom = parseInt($(this).css('margin-bottom'));
        total = total + currentTop + currentBottom;
    });
    return total;
}

alert('The total of the margins is: ' + allMargins());
```

I added a .container div to limit the * selector, otherwise it would also include the html and the body tags, which are not consistent about the margin (I had 8 pixels).

The solutions above are faster, but this is more solid.